# How to get Customer Id in Cron job function?

Tags: magento2, customer, cron, customer-session, magento-cron

```
namespace Cron\Test\Cron;
class Example {
      protected $customerSession;

        /**
         * Construct
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);

            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        }

        public function customer()
        {

           return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

        }

       public function execute()
       {

            $suser_id= $this>customer();
           $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');  
        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
        $sql = "UPDATE `total_cashback` SET is_active= 150 WHERE user_id = '$suser_id' ";  
         //$sql = "UPDATE `wallet_discounts` SET is_active = 1 WHERE customer_id = '$customerId' ";  
        $connection->query($sql);
       }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve here?

Comment: I need to update active_is column to specific value where user_id is current logged in user after some specific time.

Comment: Hi @RameshKR do you have any solution for this issue?